# Selenium raw page source

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the source code of a particular site with the help of Selenium with:

Python code:

```
driver.page_source
```

But it returns it after it has been encoded.

The raw file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>&#x41;&#x41;&#x41;&#x41;&#x41;&#x41;&#x41;&#x41;</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

When press 'View page source' inside Chrome, I saw the correct source raw without encoding.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Javascript instead of Python builtin code to get the page source.

```
javascriptPageSource = driver.execute_script("return document.body.outerHTML;")
```

Comment: If you need also the header section, use document.body.parentElement.outerHTML